# execute filter chain before admin generator symfony

Tags: filter, symfony-1.4, admin, generator, apostrophe-cms

I need to call a filter added to the filter chain before calling an action build with the admin generator.
But it seems that the filter chain is not executed before the admin generator.

Is there any workaround?

Edit: I am using apostrophe sandbox. I need to change the database connection at runtime because I have one database per client and I am doing that in a filter. but for the pages that use admin generator the filter is not called and I get the following error.

```
at Doctrine_Manager->getCurrentConnection()
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Manager.php line 558 ...
at Doctrine_Manager->getConnectionForComponent('Tag')
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Core.php line 1090 ...
at Doctrine_Core::getTable('Tag')
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\generator\sfDoctrineGenerator.class.php line 41 ...
at sfDoctrineGenerator->configure()
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\generator\sfModelGenerator.class.php line 56 ...
at sfModelGenerator->generate(array('model_class' => 'Tag', 'theme' => 'aAdmin', 'non_verbose_templates' => 1, 'with_show' => , 'singular' => null, 'plural' => null, 'route_prefix' => 'a_tag_admin', 'with_doctrine_route' => 1, 'config' => array('list' => array('sort' => array('name', 'asc'), 'title' => 'Tags Admin', 'display' => array('=name', 'tag_aBlogPost', 'tag_aEvent', 'tag_aMediaItem', 'tag_aPage'), 'fields' => array('name' => array('label' => 'Tag'), 'tag_aPage' => array('label' => 'Pages'), 'tag_aMediaItem' => array('label' => 'Media'), 'tag_aEvent' => array('label' => 'Events'), 'tag_aBlogPost' => array('label' => 'Blog'), 'tab_aEvent' => array('label' => 'aEvent')), 'object_actions' => array(), 'actions' => array('new' => array('label' => '<span class="icon"></span> New Tag', 'action' => 'new', 'params' => array('class' => 'a-btn big icon a-add')), 'clean' => array('label' => '<span class="icon"></span> Clean Tags', 'action' => 'clean', 'params' => array('class' => 'a-btn big a-show-busy')))), 'form' => array('class' => 'aTagForm'), 'filter' => null, 'edit' => array('title' => 'Edit Tag'), 'new' => array('title' => 'New Tag')), 'moduleName' => 'aTagAdmin'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\generator\sfGeneratorManager.class.php line 113 ...
at sfGeneratorManager->generate('aTagAdminGenerator', array('model_class' => 'Tag', 'theme' => 'aAdmin', 'non_verbose_templates' => 1, 'with_show' => , 'singular' => null, 'plural' => null, 'route_prefix' => 'a_tag_admin', 'with_doctrine_route' => 1, 'config' => array('list' => array('sort' => array('name', 'asc'), 'title' => 'Tags Admin', 'display' => array('=name', 'tag_aBlogPost', 'tag_aEvent', 'tag_aMediaItem', 'tag_aPage'), 'fields' => array('name' => array('label' => 'Tag'), 'tag_aPage' => array('label' => 'Pages'), 'tag_aMediaItem' => array('label' => 'Media'), 'tag_aEvent' => array('label' => 'Events'), 'tag_aBlogPost' => array('label' => 'Blog'), 'tab_aEvent' => array('label' => 'aEvent')), 'object_actions' => array(), 'actions' => array('new' => array('label' => '<span class="icon"></span> New Tag', 'action' => 'new', 'params' => array('class' => 'a-btn big icon a-add')), 'clean' => array('label' => '<span class="icon"></span> Clean Tags', 'action' => 'clean', 'params' => array('class' => 'a-btn big a-show-busy')))), 'form' => array('class' => 'aTagForm'), 'filter' => null, 'edit' => array('title' => 'Edit Tag'), 'new' => array('title' => 'New Tag')), 'moduleName' => 'aTagAdmin'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\config\sfGeneratorConfigHandler.class.php line 82 ...
at sfGeneratorConfigHandler::getContent(object('sfGeneratorManager'), 'aTagAdminGenerator', array('model_class' => 'Tag', 'theme' => 'aAdmin', 'non_verbose_templates' => 1, 'with_show' => , 'singular' => null, 'plural' => null, 'route_prefix' => 'a_tag_admin', 'with_doctrine_route' => 1, 'config' => array('list' => array('sort' => array('name', 'asc'), 'title' => 'Tags Admin', 'display' => array('=name', 'tag_aBlogPost', 'tag_aEvent', 'tag_aMediaItem', 'tag_aPage'), 'fields' => array('name' => array('label' => 'Tag'), 'tag_aPage' => array('label' => 'Pages'), 'tag_aMediaItem' => array('label' => 'Media'), 'tag_aEvent' => array('label' => 'Events'), 'tag_aBlogPost' => array('label' => 'Blog'), 'tab_aEvent' => array('label' => 'aEvent')), 'object_actions' => array(), 'actions' => array('new' => array('label' => '<span class="icon"></span> New Tag', 'action' => 'new', 'params' => array('class' => 'a-btn big icon a-add')), 'clean' => array('label' => '<span class="icon"></span> Clean Tags', 'action' => 'clean', 'params' => array('class' => 'a-btn big a-show-busy')))), 'form' => array('class' => 'aTagForm'), 'filter' => null, 'edit' => array('title' => 'Edit Tag'), 'new' => array('title' => 'New Tag')), 'moduleName' => 'aTagAdmin'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\config\sfGeneratorConfigHandler.class.php line 75 ...
at sfGeneratorConfigHandler->execute(array('C:/wamp/www/sfprojects/asandbox/plugins/apostrophePlugin/modules/aTagAdmin/config/generator.yml', 'C:\wamp\www\sfprojects\asandbox\apps\frontend/modules/aTagAdmin/config/generator.yml'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\config\sfConfigCache.class.php line 108 ...
at sfConfigCache->callHandler('modules/aTagAdmin/config/generator.yml', array('C:/wamp/www/sfprojects/asandbox/plugins/apostrophePlugin/modules/aTagAdmin/config/generator.yml', 'C:\wamp\www\sfprojects\asandbox\apps\frontend/modules/aTagAdmin/config/generator.yml'), 'C:\wamp\www\sfprojects\asandbox\cache\frontend\dev\config/modules_aTagAdmin_config_generator.yml.php')
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\config\sfConfigCache.class.php line 197 ...
at sfConfigCache->checkConfig('modules/aTagAdmin/config/generator.yml', 1)
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\config\sfConfigCache.class.php line 249 ...
at sfConfigCache->import('modules/aTagAdmin/config/generator.yml', , 1)
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\controller\sfController.class.php line 186 ...
at sfController->forward('aTagAdmin', 'index')
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\controller\sfFrontWebController.class.php line 48 ...
at sfFrontWebController->dispatch()
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\util\sfContext.class.php line 170 ...
at sfContext->dispatch()
in SF_ROOT_DIR\web\index.php line 10 ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "before the admin generator" ? Because in fact, filter chain in executed just after the routing, so before almost everything.

Comment: well it´s not executing in my case. I am using apostrophe CMS Sandbox and the filter chain is not fired.

Comment: Could you show us your filters.yml for the frontend end, I guess? (or the one which is in problem)